# Merge several images and Export a GeoTiff File

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, mosaic

I have approx 500 geo-referenced images that I was hoping to merge into 1 geo-referenced file, and export it as a single geotiff file. To be used in AutoCAD Civil 3D

I know I am pushing my luck and that QGIS moves. I get an error if I tried to merge all the files in 1 go. Same happens if I try building a virtual raster catelogue.

I have tried merging the files in 5 groups, by either building a virtual raster catelogue or merging the files. Then merging the 5 groups into 1 file.

However the above solutions all result in a blank image from exported (Layer -> Save As)

I have read building a pyramid may help using the .vrt file.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to Mosaic adjacent images (rather than merge images that may be co-incident) ? In which case you can try [GDAL_Merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html), part of GDAL.

Comment: Five *hundred* images? How big are they? I can see that quickly getting out of hand and generating a multi-terrabyte file (and that's just output, not in memory processing).

Comment: We have to produce HIRES aerial maps on A1 plans so yes the resolution is critical. Thus the image file will be massive. Each geo-referenced image file was 400-500KB so it would be close to a gigabyte in size.
Is the merge function (Raster --> Miscellaneous --> Merge) not already incorporating the GDAL_Merge?

Comment: KB or MB? KB seems mighty small for an image, especially 'hi-res'. MB seems more likely in which case you're not looking at a gig output (that'd be like two), you're looking at more like 250GB. How much memory is on the machine? What is the specific error you get? Is there a reason you don't just use the image tiles in CAD (especially so you can just turn on/off as needed when you're only doing an A1 area at a time - though I guess you don't mention what scale that's at)? Are you getting a blank *after completion* (note it may create a holding file to write to long before it's actually done).

Comment: The images that come out of Nearmaps are that size you cannot improve the resolution above that. Hence why I wanted to create a HI-RES image from heaps of smaller images. I have now created an image which is in WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. However when I click save as (with the respective layer selected), even though I change the coordinates to MGA and in the save as dialog box the coordinate extents are to MGA, when I import into AutoCAD Civil 3D the insertion point is in WGS 84 system. How do I get around this.

Comment: When I try to build the virtual raster (catalogue) with all 500 pictures I get the error "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program." It will work if it is under 350 pictures. However it would be ideal if anyone has solutions to use the 500 pictures.